# Karma Unit test: ERROR in Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have the same problem when running karma unit tests. here is my findings

one of my unit test will write data to a json file. and i get this error

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15460:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15389:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15338:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (...\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15192:29)
    at new TypeScriptFileRefactor (...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\refactor.js:79:35)
    at Object.findLazyRoutes (...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\lazy_routes.js:18:22)
    at AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst (...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:220:50)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:499:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

I added a console.log statements at `createSourceFile()` and at `AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst`.

i noticed the following in `AotPlugin._findLazyRoutesInAst`.
`for (const filePath of changedFilePaths) { }`. I added a `console.log` statement to see what was in the changedFilePaths, I noticed the following:

> These are changedFilePaths ==>
>   [ '.../src/polyfills.ts',
>   '.../src'   **<--- Please note the missing file name.**
>   ]

Hence, i am getting the above error.

This happens when i make changes to any files (irrespective of .ts files). I tried modifying a json file and the above happened.
I tried the following:

in karma.conf.js ([as per the official config docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html)), i added

`exclude: ["./src/nonCodeRelatedData/**"]`.
and

```
files: [ {pattern: "./src/nonCodeRelatedData/**", watched: false, included: false, served: false}]
```

But no luck.

Could someone point me the remedy to this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with angular 4 and angular-cli 1.6.8 - 1.7.3... Current workaround would be to change a file in node_modules as described here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053#issuecomment-366315926 or upgrade to angular 5 (not tried myself)

Comment: I had to downgrade the typescript version